# Codespace extension not working on VSCODE web

Tags: visual-studio-code, codespaces

I used to code on jupyter notebook in VSCODE web, kernels connected to my Github Codespace.
But since yesterday, all the commands I'm trying to access CodeSpace extension with seems not to be working. More specifically they appear like those commands are not existing : `command 'github.codespaces.signIn' not found`

I tried different browsers from edge to chrome. I reloaded/reinstalled codespace extension. Also checked my github codespace status. None of these are the problems.

I think there might be a problem with the compatibility between VSCode and Codespace extension....? Or not. I'm desperate to find. If there is no answer for this right now, please let me know any other ways to connect python kernel on VSCode web (i cannot install python locally due to my environment).

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Please also include the version number of your codespaces extension. 3) Please check what happens if you roll back to previous versions of the extension.